# How to "Overlap" two Layouts Nativescript

Tags: android, ios, layout, nativescript

I need this Layout using Nativescript but I don't know how to do it.
The RED box has to be in front of the BLACK box with custom position.

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `AbsoluteLayout` as the container that contains the red and black box. The `Label` below are just placeholders for the black and red box. With `AbsoluteLayout`, you can then use the `left` and `top` properties similar to how you would do in css for `position: absolute`.  Something to be aware of is the order of element in your html is the order of it stacking (in terms of z-index) - the further down it is in your html, the higher the z-index.

```html
<AbsoluteLayout width="210" height="210">

    <!-- black box -->
    <Label text="no margin" left="10" top="10" width="100" height="100"/>

    <!-- red box -->
    <Label text="margin='30'" left="10" top="10" margin="30" width="100" height="90"/>

  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

*Sidenote: you could also use a `GridLayout` to layer elements (if you don't need the absolute positioning properties such as `left` or `top`)*